# How can I test Selenium test scripts? Or should I?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, selenium

I'm working in a project with a quite large suite of tests (about 800 scenarios). Our code grew quite a lot and now I'm looking for ways to test some parts of our test library. Have you ever tested (parts of) your selenium scripts? How are you doing it? I thought about using some sample pages only for these tests, but it looks like a lot of work, doesn't it?

I know I can mock `WebDriver`, but white box testing doesn't seem quite right for me. Perhaps I have not yet grasped all the mock concepts properly. Any concerns or tips?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one school of thought..

1. Create the test case manually
2. Ensure that the test case passes when a tester manually executes it
3. Create an automated selenium script to replace this test case.
4. Have a different dev or QA test the automation works correctly.
5. Integrate the automated test into some kind of nightly run.

I would not recommend having automated tests (like a unit testing or acceptence testing framework) test your selenium tests.  It seems like an unnecessary layer of test automation.

Comment: We also thought the same, but as I said, the test suite has got quite big.